# Add Link to the Quick Launch Navigation while deploying a webpart page in the module

Tags: office-365, navigation, feature, sandbox-solution, quick-launch

I like to add a navigation link under the quick launch left nav bar when a module deploys a webpart page as a file element in the feature. Is there a declarative way or do I go with feature event receiver?

The environment I m working on - Office 365 and deploying the webpart page under a feature using a Sandbox solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no declarative way to make the page deployed through File element to show up in the Quick Launch. Check the attributes of File Element here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms459213.aspx
So, using the event receiver may be a right approach.

Answer (score 2):

Add this code to your `FeatureActivated` method of the Event Receiver:

```
 public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            using (SPWeb web = (properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb))
            {
              web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
              string headingTitle = "myNavigation";  // Navigation Title
              string headingUrl = "navigationURL"; // URL of the Navigation Link

              // Get the Quick Launch headings.
              SPNavigationNodeCollection ql = web.Navigation.QuickLaunch;

              // If a Resources heading exists, get it.
              SPNavigationNode heading = ql.Cast<SPNavigationNode>().FirstOrDefault(n => n.Title == headingTitle);

              // If the Resources heading does not exist, create it.
              if (heading == null)
              {
                   heading = new SPNavigationNode(headingTitle, headingUrl);
                   heading = ql.AddAsLast(heading);
              }
              web.Update();
              web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false; 
            }
        }
```

It will add the Navigation Link on feature activation.

Comment: Gettting following error for the cast.
'Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNodeCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and no extension method 'Cast' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNodeCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
I just enumerated through the collection to get to the required SPNavigationNode.

Comment: You need to add these three references : `using Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation;`, 
`using Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation;`, `using Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing;`

Comment: Sorry, added these references but same result. FYI I m working SPO on Office 365.

Comment: It's working on Office 365 for me. If you are using 'Sharepoint Foundation' then it will not work, try on `Sharepoint Server`. If it will not working too, then activate `SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure` feature from 'Site Collection Features' & `SharePoint Server Publishing` feature from 'Site Features'.